# Order of ChannelFuture and channelActive in netty

Tags: netty

When using a ChannelFuture and an associated ChannelFutureListener like this 
`clientBootstrap.connect(remote.getHostName(), remote.getPort()).addListener(myListener);`

Does netty give any guarantees that the listeners operationComplete is called before channelActive of the handler in the pipeline? I tried to extract this information from the documentation, but didn't find any references.

Currently I'm setting a channel attribute in the handler and rely on its value in the channelActive. This however seems to fail in rare occasions. I cannot set the channel attribute upfront in the bootstrap btw.

As a side note: I use the bootstrap with an multithread eventloopGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the future is notified first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25315995)

Comment: it actually does... the future is always notified first.

Comment: @NormanMaurer So it is guaranteed, that operationComplete has run before channelActive is called? In this case, I might have spotted a bug in the implementation

Comment: @NormanMaurer Could you kindly point me to the part of the documentation stating this guarantee?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not documented anywhere as part of the API I think (we defiantly should do it tho). It's just how we implemented it across our transports etc in netty. So while this is not documented atm you can still depend on it.

Comment: A second thought: As the future is returned in the connect function it might return an already completed future. So in theory is possible to attach the listener after the channelActive is called? Or is there any mechanism preventing such mechanism?

Comment: that is true... that said you can call `connect` on the Channel and pass a `ChannelPromise` to it. Which means you can create the promise, add a listener and then pass it to connect. Not sure why it is so important for you tho....

Comment: I need a per-channel attribute, that maps some logical remote name to the connected channel. This attribute needs to be present in the channelActive call. Your advice is extremely helpful. I guess you're referring to to boostrap.register to get the channel. I'll try this and give you some feedback.

Comment: yes... you can also specify attributes on the `Bootstrap` as well.